# Set the screen view to a specific part of imageview

Tags: java, android, xml, game-development

I would like to ask is there's a way for me to kind of put the screen view into a specific part of an image view kind of like when the user start the game it will first show that spot thanks

Comment: Maybe take a bitmap screenshot of that screen and then pass the bitmap to the other activity or wherever you want and then set the image?

Comment: I'm creating a village game and I have this kind of functionality where an image view is zoomable but when starting the game, it shows the whole image when I just want to be kind of in the take the view to the main hall upon start up

Comment: Sorry. I couldnt get you.

Comment: It like in Clash of Clans where on starting up the game you will be shown the town hall that kind of functionality is what I've meant

Comment: So u want to show the entire base on startup?

Comment: no, that's my problem it shows the entire village I just wanted to show a specific part of the village